# How to configure chosen on Form API with an entity_automcomplete widget?

Tags: 8, forms

How to configure chosen field on Form API with drupal 8.
I have already installed chosen and it's works in User Interface and not in form API.

This peace of code doesn't work:

```
          $form['tags'] = array(
        '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete', 
       '#chosen' => TRUE,
        '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
        '#selection_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['tags']],
        '#title' => ('Tags'), 
        '#empty_value' => '' 
       ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't because you are using an autocomplete widget, but the project page states:

> Chosen uses the Chosen jQuery plugin to make your  elements
> more user-friendly.

So you have to refactor your form to use a `select` element, not an autocomplete.